# Updating a value in the list to be updated before and after the dml operation

Tags: list, dml, update, boolean

Im trying to update child record in parent after trigger, where i need to update this child's boolean (MA_Campaign_Qty_Boolean__c) as part of restricting some validation in child's trigger for this execution. Is this a solution advisable in terms of governor limits of execution time etc?
[image]

Comment: First step would be to remove the update from the loop, and instead add them to a list variable and do an update on that outside the loop. Have a look at the Apex best practices: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices

Comment: ... so for your example one loop to set to true, then the update of the whole list then one loop to set to false. There are probably other ways to achieve your aim.